# Помогите сверстать небольшой контейнер с элементами

Tags: html, css

Нужен блок, как на картинке. Если там что-то выглядит криво, приложу описание словами.

Есть главный блок. Он может быть расположен в любом месте на странице (вдруг эта информация повлияет на конечный результат), его размеры задаются руками и влияют на его содержимое. Контент не должен иметь возможность менять размеры блока (должен вписываться в него).

Внутри этого блока есть 3 секции:

Ширина первой и последней равны и занимают все доступное пространство в блоке.

Ширина средней секции автоматическая и зависит от ширины контента.

В средней секции есть 2 блока, расположенные вертикально. Их вертикальное положение по центру (относительно высоты главного блока).

**Важно!**

Нужна поддержка IE11

[image: Верстка]

Comment: А что вы уже пытались сделать? На чем остановились? Что получилось, а что не получилось? В заголовке написано "помогите", а не "сделайте за меня".

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, составил требования :) На самом деле я написал сюда уже после того, как перепробовал множество вариантов. Перечислять их все - тратить время тех, кто будет это читать, потому что скорее всего подошли бы все эти варианты при их правильном использовании

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверил в IE11 работает - flexbox

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.elem1,
.elem2 {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.elems {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.outer-elem {
  background: #fbfbfb;
  min-height: 30%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="elem elem1">первый блок</div>
  <div class="elem elems">
    <div class="outer-elem">первый вертикальный</div>
    <div class="outer-elem">второй вертикальный</div>
  </div>
  <div class="elem elem2">третий блок</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.block__item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  padding: 15px;
}

.block__item:first-of-type,
.block__item:last-of-type {
  width: 50%;
}

.block__item--center {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.block__child {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 15px;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__item">
    1 block
  </div>
  <div class="block__item block__item--center">
    <div class="block__childs">
      <div class="block__child">Ширина средней секции автоматическая и зависит от ширины контента.</div>
      <div class="block__child"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block__item">
    3 block
  </div>
</div>
```